# Failed to create new data into the database using the popup form

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was trying to create a popup system to create new data into the database. when I click"Create" in my index view then I find a popup form.but when I click "Save" for data save then it does not work anything. suddenly it works and saves the data into the database. but it happened just one time. but I don't understand why it's not working smoothly.

Here is my code:

Model

```
namespace Practise.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Practise.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CategoryController(ApplicationDbContext db) //input parameter
        {
            _db = db;
        }



        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.Category.ToList());
        }


        [HttpGet]

        public IActionResult Create()
        {

            Category ca = new Category();
            return PartialView("_CreatePartial", ca);
            //return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Category ca)
        {
            _db.Category.Add(ca);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("_CreatePartial", ca);

        }

    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Practise.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-model" data-target="#addEmployee" data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">Create</button>
</br></br>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <partial name="_ButtonPartial" model="@item.Id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var save = '@TempData["save"]'

            if (save!= null) {
                alertify.success(save);
            }

        })

    </script>

}
```

_CreatePartial view:

```
@model Category

<div class="modal fade" id="#addEmployee">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="#addEmployeeLabel">Add Category</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>x</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="Create">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CategoryName"> </label>
                        <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS(site.js)

```
$(function () {
    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-model"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })
    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {

        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form'); 
          var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
          var sendData = form.serialize();
            $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        })
    })
})
```

My Output:

[image]

when I press the save button I want it to save the data to DB.but it does not work.

Comment: According to your description and codes, it works well on my side. Could you please tell me is the Category's Id is auto scale or not? If the id is not auto scale that means it will always use the same id 0.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I am not understanding the meaning "auto scale".i will give you code to check this.please tell me what code I will give you to check this.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the id has enabled identity in sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change something like that for save data:

```
  public IActionResult Create()
        {

            //Category ca = new Category();
            //return PartialView("_CreatePartial", ca);
            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Category ca)
        {
            _db.Category.Add(ca);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Create View:

```
@model Practise.Models.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

    <div class="modal fade" id="#addEmployee">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="#addEmployeeLabel">Add Category</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span>x</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CategoryName"> </label>
                            <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>*@
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
               

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then successfully will save data.